# Determining the line of symmetry

Tags: functional-analysis

If $f(x)$ is the image of the reflection of $g(x)$, how do you determine the line of symmetry from the two equations?

Edit: The graph of f is the set of $(x,f(x))$ as $x$ goes over all reals. Similarly for $g$. Suppose these two subsets of the plane are assured to be related by some reflection. How to find this reflection? For example, given $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=-(x+1)^2$.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: If f(x)=g(-x) and f(-x)=g(x), how do you determine the line of symmetry from these equations?

Comment: Where does $x = -x$?